# How to draw ░░░░░░░ blank with overlaid text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, text

Wondering how to draw this sort of thing with tikz:

```
I ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ am a blank space.
```

...but with text overlaid on the dot grid. Also, instead of the dot-grid being diagonal, I would like to make it simply vertical/horizontal, and make the dots smaller and lighter so when the text goes over it it's not distracting. But it would be along these lines:

```
I ░Hello░World░░░ am a blank space.
```

But the "Hello World" would have ░ faded dots behind each letter. Just using this ░ unicode character for demo, this instead would use tikz.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? (If yes, all I'd have to do is to introduce a slightly more flexible pattern such that things look good also with more reasonable scale factors, if no, then this may help others to understand the question better.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns}
\newcommand{\PlaceCharOverDots}[2][10]{%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=temp]
\node[transparent!20,scale=#1] 
{\bfseries\sffamily \textcolor{white}{#2}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,scale=#1] (X) {\bfseries\sffamily 
\textcolor{white}{\strut#2}};
\path[pattern=dots,overlay] (X.north west)
rectangle (X.south east);%
\path[path fading=temp,fit fading=false,overlay,pattern=dots,pattern
color=gray!20] (X.north west)
rectangle (X.south east);}%
}
\begin{document}
\PlaceCharOverDots{Hello world} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you only want the text being placed over dots, all one needs to do is to define a somewhat denser dot pattern and to use it as the background of a node. I recommend `\tikzmarknode` here because it automatically detects the mode your in (math mode, font size etc.) and has other advantages, which this however does not exploit. Of course, you may adjust `inner sep` to your needs and/or replace it by `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,patterns}
% based on the rings example on p. 1060 of the pgfmanual as well as 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/1952 for the color
\makeatletter 
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[/tikz/radius,\size]{flexible dots}
{\pgfpoint{-0.5*\size}{-0.5*\size}}
{\pgfpoint{0.5*\size}{0.5*\size}}
{\pgfpoint{\size}{\size}}
{
 \pgfsetfillcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
 \pgfpathcircle\pgfpointorigin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/radius}}
 \pgfusepath{fill}
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
radius/.initial=0.1pt,
size/.store in=\size, 
size=0.5pt,
}
\begin{document}
\tikzmarknode[pattern=flexible dots,inner sep=2pt]{test}{Hello world}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty much, but the Hello World would just be plain black text, not a cutout of the dots. It's as if the blank is just a background made of dots, and you are typing right over it to fill in the blank.

Comment: @LancePollard I am not sure I fully understand yet but I added a proposal that among other things comes with a more flexible dot pattern.

Comment: copy-pasting the code into `pdflatex` I am getting an error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 \tikzmarknode
                  [pattern=flexible dots,inner sep=2pt]{test}{Hello world}`

Comment: @LancePollard When was the last time you updated your TeX installation? `\tikzmarknode` has been added only a few months to the `tikzmark` library. The error message seems to indicate that you are using an older version.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it. The TikZ pattern has been adopted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323867/8650. Instead of setting up a background layer, I simply draw the node twice.

```
   documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly{my dots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{5pt}{5pt}}{\pgfqpoint{2pt}{2pt}}%
    {
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{.4pt}
        \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
    \newcommand{\fade}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline]
    \node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (node) {#1};
    \fill[pattern=my dots, pattern color=black!10] (node.south west) rectangle (node.north east);
    \node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (node) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \begin{document}
    \ \\
    I \fade{Hello World} am a blank space.\\
    I Hello World am a blank space.
    \end{document}
```

[image: Dot pattern behind Hello World.]

Comment: @marmots answer is better - using a tikzmarknode and applying the pattern directly to that node -you just need the lighter color.