# How to customize "dots" pattern Tikz without redefining it

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pattern

Is there a simple way to customize the dots pattern? With "simple" I mean not like this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323858/how-to-change-the-density-of-a-pattern) (several lines to customize the dots). For example, I have this code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[pattern = dots] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

which produces

[image]

but I'd like to increase the distance (space) between the dots (to have less, reducing the density of dots). Or, in other case, change the color of the dots. So, is possible to do that without writing several lines of codes? Thank you for reading and helping!

The ideal answer would be this (if you replace "dots" for "Lines" it works but not for "dots"):

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[pattern = {dots[color = green, distance = 0.2cm]}] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Dots` from `patterns.meta`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[pattern={Dots[distance=.2cm]}, pattern color=green] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```